# How to match classes

Tags: java

I am using `org.json.simple.JSONObject` to transfor string json into JSONObject.

I want to check the type or class when I get a value out of it. Like this:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(resourceFile.getFile()));
JSONObject target = (JSONObject) data.get("target");
if(data.get("target") instanceof JSONArray.class) //not working
...
if(data.get("target").getClass().equals(JSONArray.class)) //not working
if(data.get("target").getClass() == JSONArray.class) //not working
...



if(data.get("target").getClass().equals("org.json.simple.JSONArray")) //this works.
```

Is there any other way to check and compare the classes?

Comment: `data.get("target") instanceof JSONArray.class` must be without `.class`

Comment: Vulcan, no. It could be JSONObject or JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(data.get("target") instanceof JSONArray)
```

worked for me as well.

In second thought, it might be happening because `JSONArray` is imported from another library? maybe `JSONArray` imported from `org.json.JSONArray` [(org.json)](http://json.org/java), while `JSONObject` is imported from `org.json.simple.JSONObject` [(org.json.simple)](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)?

I got that lead from the fact that only really specified class path worked for you (`... .equals("org.json.simple.JSONArray") ...`).

Comment: let me check back on this.

Comment: @FarazDurrani let me know if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
data.get("target").getClass().getName().equals(JSONArray.class.getName())
```